# Why does std::views::take not yield a sized_range?

Tags: c++, std-ranges, c++23

I’m using C++23. I have a function `do_something` that needs a `std::ranges::sized_range`, i.e. the size of the range should be known in constant time.

```cpp
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>


void do_something(std::ranges::sized_range auto& r);

void doesnt_work() {
    auto range = std::views::iota(0) | std::views::take(42);
    do_something(range);
}
```

([Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/PPGdTxvrc))

Why does `std::views::take` not yield a `std::ranges::sized_range`?

If I copy the elements into a vector, it works.

```cpp
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>


void do_something(std::ranges::sized_range auto& r);

void works() {
    auto range = std::views::iota(0) | std::views::take(42);
    auto container = range | std::ranges::to<std::vector>();
    do_something(container);
}
```

I don’t want to copy the elements of the range into a container (like `std::vector`), because the function `do_something` also copies the elements. I don’t want to copy them twice.

Comment: N.b. `std::views::iota(0, 42)` [is a sized range](https://godbolt.org/z/brWK1bcxh)

Comment: There is a related LWG here: https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue4050

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sized_range` is a stronger requirement than it can provide.

> The `sized_range` concept specifies the requirements of a `range` type that knows its size in constant time with the `size` function.

It would be incorrect to just report the `take` parameter, because the underlying range could be smaller. So `size` is called on the underlying range. This means that `take_view` can only be a `sized_range` if the underlying range is one too.

Hypothetically, there could be a concept `infinite_range`, and applying `take` to such a range would be sized, but that isn't how it was specified.